# ios9 piscture in picture,the window is at the right-center

Tags: pip, ios9, multitasking

I use the PIP in ios9.I found a problem.Sometime,set the viedo in PIP,but the window is not at the screen edge instead at the right-center or left-center.
Is anything i need to set?

Comment: Is this a question about how to use PIP on iOS9? If so, this is not the right place for the question. If not, and you're asking about how to implement PIP in your own app, then a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: @siburb thank you.It is my first asking question.I know how to implement PIP.But i meet the problem.Sometimes,the pip window does't at the edge of the screen.Did you meet the same problem?